# Using RequireJS in a multipage application

Tags: requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

we have a multipage application with below structure:

**ApplicationModule** is the root folder that contains all application logical modules,like **Usermanagement** and others like below:

**/ApplicaationModules/UserManagement**

//inside **userManagement** folder we have html pages and their corresponding .js(main)files
//so we have like
**login.html** and **login.js**

**Login.js** in turn requires/loads all script files that are required to execute the logic for the page, so it's configuration is like below:

```
require.config({

paths: {
    'jquery': '../../Scripts/jquery',
    'appSessionManager': '../../Scripts/ApplicationSessionManager',
    'appBasePage': '../../Scripts/ApplicationBasePage',
    'initServices': '../../IntegrationServices/Eservices/EservicesUserManagementService/Authenticate',
    'smUtility': '../../Scripts/SmartServicesUtility',
}}); 

require(['appSessionManager', 'appBasePage', 'initServices', 'smUtility', 'jquery'], 
function    (sessionManagerRef, basePageRef, eservicesRef, utilityRef) 

{ 
$(document).ready(function () {
//Here is the page code that uses other libraries like appSessionManager, appBasePage and others.
});
});
```

NOW, before moving to production, we want to use Optimizer so that all required files should be concatenated and minified as a single file.

**Standing inside UserManagement folder**, we run following command for the optimizer:
**node ../../r.js -o name=Login out=optimize.js**

BUT it is giving us the below error:

Tracing dependencies for: Login
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:[some application path]\ApplicationModules\UserManagement\appSession
Manager.js'
In module tree:
    Login

Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'D:[some application path]\ApplicationModules\UserManagement\app
SessionManager.js'
In module tree:
    Login

```
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
```

Error is clear as for **SessionManager.js** file, it is trying to find it **inside usermangement folder** but I want it to look for this file **inside Scripts folder** as mentioned in **config Paths of login.js file**.

I will highly appreciate if someone can help us out on this.

Comment: You'd be more likely to get help if your question were edited to make it easy to read.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited and tried to make it clear and readable.